# Jql query for assignee or reporter as current user and status not closed

Tags: jira, jql

The query below listing closed status as well.

`assignee = currentUser() OR reporter = currentUser() AND status not in (Closed , resolved) order by updated DESC`

When `reporter = currentUser()` is removed, `Closed` status list is not seen. How to see the results only for `non-closed` or `unresolved` statuses user `currentUser` category for assignee and reporter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, I think you just need parentheses that is covering "OR" condition:

```
(assignee = currentUser() OR reporter = currentUser()) AND status not in (Closed , resolved) order by updated DESC
```

Comment: Great, thanks, confusing quotes when compared to mysql queries